# Combining strings from 2 cells, adding a hyphen and sending using DDEPoke

Tags: vba, excel, set

I'm trying to sort something out that an ex-coworker created. I'm not much of a PC programmer.

Some Background info:

-The program is designed to take data from the worksheet and send it  to a PLC (Programmable Logic Controller). The Excel worksheet doesn't do anything with the data.

-The word "Spare" is just a string containing Spare. It doesn't come from anywhere in the program. If the cell has nothing in it when the program looks at it, then I want the program to send the word Spare to the PLC.

-Link for DDEPoke (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-ddepoke-method-excel). It sends data via a previously open channel (using DDEInitiate).

-In it's original form the program doesn't throw up any errors. But it doesn't write the data to the PLC.

Original program:

```
    For iBit = 0 To 15
            Sheets("TestPoints").Cells(3, 5) = iMod
            Sheets("TestPoints").Cells(4, 5) = iBit


            sWriteString = "IO_DescriptionStorage[" & iMod & "," & iBit & "]"
            If Sheets("TestPoints").Cells(iIONameRowNum + iBit, iColumn) = "" Then
               **DDEPoke RSIchan, sWriteString, "Spare"**
            Else
                Value = Sheets("TestPoints").Cells(iIONameRowNum + iBit, iColumn) & " - " &           Sheets("TestPoints").Cells(iDeviceStartRow + iBit, iColumn)
               **DDEPoke RSIchan, sWriteString, Value**
            End If


    Next iBit

Next iMod
```

I've been able to figure out where the problem is which I highlighted in bold.

DDEPoke RSIchan, sWriteString, "Spare" is just trying to send the string "Spare" if the cell is empty.

DDEPoke RSIchan, sWriteString, Value is trying to send the contents of the variable Value.

Starting with the code in the Else statement, through trial and error I found there is 2 ways I can get the program to send data but only the data in 1 cell.

1.

```
 Set Value = Sheets("TestPoints").Cells(iIONameRowNum + iBit, iColumn) 

              DDEPoke RSIchan, sWriteString, Value
```

2.

```
DDEPoke RSIchan, sWriteString, Sheets("TestPoints").Cells(iIONameRowNum + iBit, iColumn)
```

What I'm trying to do is combine and send, so I tried the following:

1.

```
    Set Value = Sheets("TestPoints").Cells(iIONameRowNum + iBit, iColumn) & " - " & Sheets("TestPoints").Cells(iDeviceStartRow + iBit, iColumn)

DDEPoke RSIchan, sWriteString, Value
```

This throws an error when it tries to Set the Value Run-time error '13': Type mismatch. So this isn't the right way to use the Set keyword

2.

```
DDEPoke RSIchan, sWriteString, Sheets("TestPoints").Cells(iIONameRowNum + iBit, iColumn) & " - " & Sheets("TestPoints").Cells(iDeviceStartRow + iBit, iColumn)
```

This doesn't throw any errors but it doesn't write anything to the PLC.

I'm pretty sure it's just a matter of packaging the data up correctly for the Set keyword and/or DDEPoke method.

I think once I get the code in the Else statement working I will be able to apply it to code in the If statement.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Shane

Comment: Does your code work when sending "Spare"? Inserting a line `Debug.Print Value` before the 2nd DDEPoke statement will allow you to inspect the data you're sending to the PLC so you can verify it's a string the PLC can handle. Is `Value` of Type String or Variant? I concur with @Night1505 that you should not need to use `Set`. If `Set` works then `Value` must be an `Object` and may not be a suitable data type for DDEPoke.

Answer (score 0):

Doing some simple testing, I can get the concatenated value with the following:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim Value As Variant

    Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(24, 8) & " - " & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(25, 8)

    MsgBox Value
End Sub
```

The 'Set' Keyword shouldn't need to be used here at all, since you're just assigning a value to the variable, not an object. However, if it's not working for you, you're probably accurate that it is due to the way it's being passed to the DDEPoke method.

You might try first storing your full concatenated string in a string variable, then assigning that to your Value, like so:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim str As String
    Dim Value As Variant

    str = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(24, 8) & " - " & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(25, 8)
    Value = str

    DDEPoke RSIchan, sWriteString, Value
End Sub
```

EDIT:
If the Set keyword is the key, then it seems as though the object is not "becoming" what it needs to be. In the example of DDEPoke you linked above, it shows the 3rd argument being set to a range, so I wonder if you add a column to your sheet with a CONCATENATE formula to create the string you're trying to send, then store it. Let's say you're formula is in column H, for example:

```
Set Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & rowNum)
```

I hope this tactic works! :)

Comment: Thanks for your time Night1505.

I was able to store the concatenated string but ran into trouble again because without the set key word it doesn't send it. I tried Set Value = str but it won't compile. The error says "Object  required.

Comment: Edited to try to more closely follow the example of DDEPoke you linked in OP.